# I can't update Windows 10 on my Toshiba Satellite Pro C850

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro C850 with an intel core i5 3230M CPU running Windows 10 and I can't update windows. Every time I try to update, it comes up with an error saying 'We couldn’t connect to the update service. We’ll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn’t work, make sure that you’re connected to the Internet.' Please help

Comment: which windows 10 build (1507, 1511, 1607) do you use?

Comment: How do you find which windows 10 build you have

Comment: never mind. I have windows 10 build 1607

Comment: download the MSU: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3200970 and install the update on your own

Comment: I've installed the update but its still having the same problem

Comment: have you installed any "tweaking/tuning" or "disable win10 spy" tool? they only damage Windows.

Comment: not that I know of

Comment: this user had the same issue and malware casued it: http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/62813-unable-update-windows-update-cannot-connect-update-service-post803446.html#post803446 so also scan the PC and also try the linked troubleshooter

Answer (score 0):

I have done a full virus scan with Trend Micro Maximum Security and it found 6 viruses and removed them. I am now receiving updates through windows update